# Prettier: how to force 1 spacing line between sections?

Tags: line, space, prettier

so lets say my code is:

```
function test(){
}
function test2(){
}
```

and after prettier, i want it to look like:

```
function test(){
}

function test2(){
}
```

is it possible and if so, how/where?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Prettier did not work for me. I am using Beautify